# How to fix boundaries

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to follow the tutorial by Christian Thompson - the tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw1H3rG3POM&list=PLlEgNdBJEO-kXk2PyBxhSmo84hsO3HAz2&index=4).

However, the ball and paddles aren't affected by the boundary.

I've tried rewriting the code and copying it exactly but it always ends up failing

```
if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1
    score_b += 1

if ball.ycor() > -290:
    ball.sety(-290)
    ball.dy *= -1
    score_a += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing I immediately notice is that the second if statement should read:

```
if ball.ycor() < -290:
```

You want to check if it's **less than** -290. Any ball in play will always be greater than -290, which is probably why it's breaking, because that if statement is firing every loop.